# Error when defining a firefox WebExtensions options page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am currently working on a rather simple add-on for Firefox using the new WebExtensions API. All is well up until the point I try to define `options_ui` in the manifest file. When set, loading the extension results in the following error:

> There was an error during installation: getURL may not be called before an `id` or `uuid` has been set.

Full manifest:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "MyExtension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "...",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/48.png",
    "96": "icons/96.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "*://*.example.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/32.png",
    "default_title": "MyExtension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  }
}
```

The problem **does not** occur if `options_ui` is unset, and the extension works as expected, apart from the missing options page, of course.

What could be the source of this error? Why does it only happen with `options_ui`? `browser_action.default_popup` has a URL, too, and that works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is apparently a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269454). A workaround right now is to set `applications.gecko.id` manually.

```
"applications": {
  "gecko": {
    "id": "my-extension@example.com"
  }
}
```